# Загрузка файла на сервер с изменением названия

Tags: php

Вроде подобного не нашёл. Как можно реализовать загрузка файла на сервер с изменением его названия на рандомную строчку. Вот куски кода 
Проверка расширения

```
     $file = array_shift($_FILES['icons']);
 $ext = substr($file,1+strrpos($file,"."));
 $fati = array("jpg","png");
 if(in_array($ext,$fati)){

 }else{
   $errors[]= "Иконка может быть только jpg/png";
 }
```

поле в котором указываем файл

у поля загрузки name="icons"
код рандомчика для имени

```
$name = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 40);
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, а для чего `$name = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 40);` - вот этот код нужен?

Comment: генерация рандомной строчки 40 символов в длину :D

Comment: Это так не работает) Максимум 32 символа получите и не больше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот накидал по быстрому, что то вроде такого получается

Если загрузка сразу нескольких файлов

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}

$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['icons']);

foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
    $file = $_FILES['name']; // icon.jpg
    $fdata = pathinfo($file);
    $ext = $fdata['extension'];     // jpg
    $filename = $fdata['filename']; // icon

    if($ext == 'jpg' or $ext == 'png'){
        $name = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 40);
        $newname = $name .'.'. $ext;
        echo $newname; // пример: 45yt45unufnt45uny54ny45fy45yf45yf45.jpg
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Иконка может быть только jpg/png";
    }
}
```

Если закрузка одного файла

```
$file = $_FILES['icons']['name']; // icon.jpg
$fdata = pathinfo($file);

$ext = $fdata['extension'];     // jpg
$filename = $fdata['filename']; // icon

if($ext == 'jpg' or $ext == 'png'){
    $name = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 40);
    $newname = $name .'.'. $ext;
    echo $newname; // пример: 45yt45unufnt45uny54ny45fy45yf45yf45.jpg
}else{
    $errors[] = "Иконка может быть только jpg/png";
}
```